# Run js once an image has been lazy loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this lazy load jQuery script ( http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload ) to lazy load images when they appear in the viewport, but I want to run some javascript / styling to style the new, full image that is loaded.

How can I run javascript once the image has been loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery Lazy Load plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) has a callback parameter called 
***appear***, that gets triggered for every image, once it's been loaded. Use it like this, in this case e.g. to put a red border on the image, once it's loaded (*this* in the callback refers the raw DOM img object):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("img").lazyload({
            appear: function () {
                //Image is loaded. Put javascript here.
                this.style = "border: 1px solid red";
            }
        });
    });
```

Although I will say, if you wanna add styling to the image, you should use css instead. But there might be cases where you actually wanna trigger javascript on image-load, and this seems like the way to do it with the lazy load plugin :)

Answer (score 1):

Bind a handler to the image [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Attribute/onload) event. But be aware that you have to set the handler fore every image, as the `load` event doesn't bubble up the DOM tree. Here is a way:

```
$('#img').on('load', function() {
    //do some styling...
});
```

However, my experience tells me that, with this event it's better if you use the `onclick` attribute. It my happen that, when you set the handler via jQuery, some images have already loaded.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. The selector needs to be changed to `$('img')`

Comment: This is not working, I applied it to all my images with `$('.loadMeLater').on('load'...`, but the styling is not taking effect when the new image is loaded. Is it perhaps styling when the placeholder image is loaded?

Comment: Try adding the handler inline with 'onload'. The load event is tricky, as I said.